# Declaring object property type in function param

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

This problem has me so confused, I don't even know how to properly title this question.

I started learning TypeScript a couple of hours ago and I've run into a brick wall with a `Property 'whatever' does not exist on type 'object'.` intellisense error.

I get the feeling that I'm supposed to declare an interface for this object that defines the property in question, but that feels wrong, since the object is an event listener parameter, so I don't call the function directly - the library that I'm using does. It also feels like an interface for something that I'll literally only use once is overkill.

Let me show you what I mean:

```
// this event listener is created by the library I'm using, so I can't change the params it sends
this.load.on('fileprogress', (file: object) => {
  console.log(`Loading asset: ${file.key}`); // ".key" is crapping out with "Property 'key' does not exist on type 'object'."
});
```

The easiest solution seems to be just doing `(file) => {...}` so that it defaults to type `any`, but I want to avoid that, otherwise I might as well go back to using plain old JavaScript. The next thing I came up with is declaring `interface File { key: string }` above the event listener and then changing the function to `(file: File) => {...}`, but that feels like a hack because, like I said, I'm not the one calling this function and have zero control over what's *actually* getting sent as the parameter. Also, the whole `interface File...` feels overly verbose.

What I was thinking, along the interface lines, is isn't there some way to inline declare the properties' types in the parameter list. Something like `(file: object { key: string })`? This will still be a hack if we think of it literally as an inline interface, but at least we're now telling it what properties the object is expected to have, right?

One thing I came up with which isn't throwing an intellisense error is this monstrosity `(file: {[key: string]: any} = {}) => {}`, but there's that dreaded `any` keyword again, and intellisense is reporting this as a... Well, I don't even know what it's supposed to be. Here's a screenshot.

[image: what even is that??]

I guess the bottom line question that I'm asking is what's the correct way to handle this type of situation where a function that you don't call directly needs to receive an object with properties you can't predict and thus can't define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic TypeScript typing for this is `Record<string, unknown>`. That assumes that you will receive an object with string property names, but assumes nothing about specific property names or what types their values might have. You will then need to perform runtime [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) tests in order to safely access any property of this object. So, for example:

```
this.load.on('fileprogress', (file: Record<string, unknown>) => {
    if (typeof file.key === 'string') {
        console.log(`Loading asset: ${file.key}`);
    }
});
```

(Note that the `typeof` guard here is not necessary to simply say `.key`, as a `Record` object will allow any string property name. It is necessary to confirm the value's existence and type [I guessed `string`]).

However, are you sure that the library you are using makes absolutely no representation about the shape of the object it passes to you? That seems unusual even for a plain JS library. Many, if not most, libraries even have their own TypeScript typings now (either directly or through `@types/*` packages), making these argument types implicit.

Comment: I didn't even know the words to articulate my problem, then you came along and cleared the whole thing up for me, so many thanks! About your last question - I'm actually not sure if the library *really* makes no representation about the shape of the object - it probably does somewhere in the `node_modules`. But I'm not sure if I wanted to go edit interfaces in there. That being said, I again don't really know what I'm talking about here, so if you have more advice to offer in this regard, or know how this situation *should* be handled, I'll gladly hear it.

Comment: No need to edit the library's code. You can try installing `@types/[library-package-name]` as a `--dev` dependency; if that works, the type of the `file` arg should become implicit and you won't have to specify it at all. If not, you should be able to consult the library's documentation and define argument types based on that. For example, you could say `(file: { key: string })` if the `file` arg is an object with one property, `key`, whose value is a `string`.